# A simple formulation to calculate the sequence and rate of salt precipitation in a brine?

Tags: oceanography, geochemistry, precipitation, sedimentology, evaporation

Is there a simple formulation to estimate the rate of salt precipitation in a brine given its ion concentrations and the evaporation rate?

For example: if we know the concentrations of Cl<sup>−</sup>, Na<sup>+</sup>, Mg<sup>2+</sup>, SO<sub>4</sub><sup>2−</sup>, Ca<sup>2+</sup>, K<sup>+</sup> of a sea-water brine at a known temperature *T*, what salt(s) and how much of each will precipitate for a given evaporation rate *E* (assuming time enough for equilibrium)?
Can you refer to a concise text-book or article?

I need something that goes beyond the simplistic saturation concentration concept (i.e., prescribed limit for diluted salt concentration). The effects of life in the solution can be dismissed.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a link to a hydrochemical consultant, Dr. C.A.J. Appelo, and the public-domain software FREEQC.

It can be downloaded from [here](http://www.hydrochemistry.eu/)

This link leads to an [example](http://www.hydrochemistry.eu/exmpls/sea_evap.html) of salt precipitation rates when evaporating sea water.

The formulation used is detailed in a second [manual](http://www.hydrochemistry.eu/ph3/manual2_eqns.pdf)

Comment: truly a helpful brief answer, thanks. I see two problems, though: 1) the code is not open source (as I understand from the site), and 2) the formulation manual is not very accessible for dummies as me. So it is impossible (for me) to reproduce their calcualtions.